# PHP curl output is encoded? My IF is wrong?

Tags: php, if-statement, curl

I'm newbie with curl and php. Actually i'm work on this sample code:

I'm using this API to receive the response in Newline (\n).

```
$client_ip = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward_ip = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (filter_var($client_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
 $visitor_ip = $client_ip;        
} elseif (filter_var($forward_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
 $visitor_ip = $forward_ip;
} else {
 $visitor_ip = $remote_ip;
}

$url = "http://ip-api.com/line/".$visitor_ip."?fields=city";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$visitor_city = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $visitor_city;
```

Result:

```
New York
```

The result is correct. I'm in New York, the code show my city. But when i add IF, something as wrong:

```
if ($visitor_city == "New York") {
    echo " TRUE!";
}
```

My result with this if:

```
New York
```

But i want if result

```
New York TRUE!
```

I'm miss something? Server configuration?

Comment: can you show what is the output of `var_dimp($visitor_city);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try one with `trim()`:-

```
if (trim($visitor_city) == "New York") {
    echo " TRUE!";
}
```

Comment: @ArtaxerxesSaint's it remove white-space from starting and trailing of a string

Answer (score 1):

I would add a debug line output to see if there's any whitespace around that return value.

```
echo "<pre>(".$visitor_city.")</pre>";
```

If you see any new lines or space between "New York" and your parens, then there's white space, so the if eval would return false.

It's even possible that there is HTML in the return value.

Maybe even a simple 
`echo strlen($visitor_city);` 
would help, since you could count the expected characters and if it's more, there's whitespace and/or HTML tags.

or just print any special HTML characters
`echo htmlspecialchars($visitor_city);`

You could even just view source on your output and see if there's any extra content there.